# libgcc_s.so.1 must be installed for pthread_cancel to work on Ubuntu

Tags: python, linux, bash, gcc, module

I'm running a program on Linux that requires gcc. I am using a High Performance Cluster, so packages are loaded using `module load` (so when I want to load gcc I use `module load gcc`). But, when I call the program (OpenNMT-py, which is well maintained and has a fair-sized community around it) it throws the error:

```
[2020-09-01 23:47:30,247 INFO] Extracting features...
[2020-09-01 23:47:30,352 INFO]  * number of source features: 0.
[2020-09-01 23:47:30,352 INFO]  * number of target features: 0.
[2020-09-01 23:47:30,352 INFO] Building `Fields` object...
[2020-09-01 23:47:30,353 INFO] Building & saving training data...
[2020-09-01 23:47:32,874 INFO] Building shard 0.
[2020-09-01 23:48:16,137 INFO]  * saving 0th train data shard to data-bin-0109-onmt/data.train.0.pt.
libgcc_s.so.1 must be installed for pthread_cancel to work
./train_0109_onmt.sh: line 5: 49358 Aborted                 onmt_preprocess -train_src full_corp0507/train.en -train_tgt full_corp0507/train.ga -valid_src full_corp0507/dev.en -valid_tgt full_corp0507/dev.ga -save_data data-bin-0109-onmt/data
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/ichec/work/ichum001c/Aistrigh/bin/onmt_train", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/ichec/work/ichum001c/Aistrigh/lib/python3.7/site-packages/onmt/bin/train.py", line 197, in main
    train(opt)
  File "/ichec/work/ichum001c/Aistrigh/lib/python3.7/site-packages/onmt/bin/train.py", line 39, in train
    vocab = torch.load(opt.data + '.vocab.pt')
  File "/ichec/work/ichum001c/Aistrigh/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/serialization.py", line 571, in load
    with _open_file_like(f, 'rb') as opened_file:
  File "/ichec/work/ichum001c/Aistrigh/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/serialization.py", line 229, in _open_file_like
    return _open_file(name_or_buffer, mode)
  File "/ichec/work/ichum001c/Aistrigh/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/serialization.py", line 210, in __init__
    super(_open_file, self).__init__(open(name, mode))
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'data-bin-0109-onmt/data.vocab.pt'
```

But more importantly is the `libgcc_s.so.1 must be installed for pthread_cancel` bit. I assume it just can't find gcc, but when I submit my scripts, I always make sure gcc is loaded and even test it beforehand by typing `gcc` and I always get the output:

```
gcc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
```

Which suggests that gcc can be found and used. I have tried using different hardware (GPU/CPU) but beyond that I'm not sure where the problem may lie. Perhaps I can explicitly point to gcc but I cannot find its environment variable(s)

Comment: You might try to run `gcc --version ` and `which gcc` to figure out whether you're really using the compiler that you want. Maybe you're using the one installed on the system by default, but not the one loaded with `lmod`? Also, module files on clusters often set an evironment variable when set by default, maybe something like `$GCC_ROOT` could help you link the correct libraries.

Comment: @mivkov Sorry for getting back so late. Before `module load gcc`, `gcc --version` shows I'm using v4.8.5 but after it's v8.2.0. I'm currently trying to see what versions my required library supports but I'm nearly sure v8.2.0 is supported. I'll also take a look at `$GCC_ROOT` and get back to you. Thanks for replying.